# iptables port forwarding

Tags: linux, iptables, fedora, port-forwarding

I have a linksys router that is letting traffic through just fine, but when I try to let that same traffic through to my linux box (fedora 10) it stalls.  I've followed every iptable rule I can find to no avail.  If I chkconfig iptables off -> reboot. Voila. But obviously I don't want to leave things like that.

Any ideas?  Any "tools" to see exactly what ports are or are not open?

Answer (score 1):

- nmap: scan for open ports.
- netcat: like telnet, but on steroids. the swiss army knife of connection debugging. great for manually connecting to ports and shoving data in.
- Wireshark: packet sniffer. can grab everything off the network if your card supports promiscuous mode (I think every ethernet card does.) great for double-checking that your traffic in and out looks how you'd expect.

I would also recommend rechecking your IPtables rules. OUTPUT can be a bit challenging.

Answer (score 0):

nmap can check open ports. Can we have some more information? What iptables rules are you using? A little more information. What ports are you trying to block?

Comment: well, I want to block ALL ports, then allow only the few I need apps to get data through.  For instance, the basics, 80, 21, 25, 3306.. I want those open, and say something new like 2106?  How do I (syntax please) open those ports for incoming traffic to an application running on the box?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an easier way of writing iptables rules, you can check out [Firehol](http://firehol.sourceforge.net/) which makes this very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a syntax for making iptables rules, since there are lots of tutorials out in the web describing this much better than I can. If you want to debug your existing rules, then

- post the output of your `iptables -vL` and, so that we know what rules you are using currently, and
- have a look at the output of `iptables -vL` yourself: The first column tells you how many packets matched the given rule. If it shows zero, it means that the packets have probably been matched by an earlier rule.